# Interface is Modifier or not

Tags: java, interface

Interface Is a modifier Or not in Java?

Answer (score 0):

It can indirectly be considered as modifier because :

1) Interface is also called as 100% pure abstract class.

2) Internally interface treated as abstract.

*Sample Code :-

```
final interface Sample
```

{

}
//javac Sample.java

*Output:-

Sample.java:1: error: illegal combination of modifiers: interface and final
final interface Sample
      ^
1 error

Press any key to continue...